# Почему не применяется css правило к дочерним тегам, когда обращаюсь к родительскому тегу div?

Tags: html, css

Помогите пожалуйста, я новичок и не могу понять в чем дело. Я думал, что если применять css правила к родительским тегам, то и на доч. теги распространяется.

```css
div {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#!">Hello world</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Есть наследуемые свойства и ненаследуемые. А list-style-type к спискам применяется

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У `li` и `а`  применяются разные стили,   у `li` применяются маркеры, а у `a` применяется подчеркивание.

```css
a{
    text-decoration: none;
       }
li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#!">Hello world</a></li>
     </ul>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Pavel Nazarian исправил ответ

Comment: В тексте одно, в коде другое, а на вопрос вдобавок никак ничто не отвечает  

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский исправил ответ